# Client side to server side Data Passing C# MVC

Tags: jquery, asp.net-mvc, model-view-controller

Is there any alternative method to pass and call the controller method in MVC.

Normally I know,

```
@Html.Beginform('MethodName','Controller Name')
```

or

```
<form action="/{Controller Name}/{Method Name}" method="post">  
    <div>My Html Form</div>       
</form>
```

And

```
$.ajax({
    type: "POST",
    data: {},
    url: "../{Controller Name}/{Method Name}",
    successs: function(response) {},
    error: function(response) {}
});
```

Is there any alternative method is there? If there let me explain that's use and description.

Comment: What problem are you trying to solve? Both of those code fragments have 'predecessors' - more primitive verbose ways of calling. Here's a "primitive" way in javascript: https://blog.garstasio.com/you-dont-need-jquery/ajax/ The "primitive" way in razor is to hand write out the form definition

Comment: I guess by "client" in this case you mean purely from a web browser, not a think client

Comment: @Nick.McDermaid This both are working fine, No problem with this. Just need to know any alter native methods to call controller.

Comment: `Form` or `Ajax` are the two main ways of returning data to the server/Controller. There are frameworks available to support these. They are well supported, have tutorials and plentiful examples. What is your underlying question?

Comment: yes there are ways, but it's not clear what you are looking for?

Comment: @Nick.McDermaid We using Html with Jquery . that's why i am mentioning Client

Comment: @PeterSmith i am just looking for any alternative method like this..

Comment: They all boil down to the same method. Any other method you find within a browser is just a wrapper around a HTML form or a javascript XMLHttpRequest

Comment: @Nick.McDermaid XMLHttpRequest means

Comment: `XMLHttpRequest` is the protocol behind Ajax

Comment: @Nick.McDermaid Actually this is not a problem. May be questioner is wanting to know how ways a form can be submitted in ASP.NET MVC!

Comment: @TanvirArjel Correct

Comment: @ElangoS Check my answer! I have shown another  one as you are expecting!

Comment: @TanvirArjel Sure I will check and Update you

Comment: If you had followed the link I posted in my prior comment you would see an example of XMLHttpRequest. Further..... you can learn yourself if you google

Comment: @Nick.McDermaid Sure

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Yes! there is another one as you are expecting and that is:

```
@using (Ajax.BeginForm("MethodName", "ControllerName", new AjaxOptions {
    InsertionMode = InsertionMode.Replace, 
    UpdateTargetId = "targetReplaceId", //target div that will be replaced with the response
    LoadingElementId = "loader" // div with .gif loader - that is shown when data are loading   
}))
{
    // Here is your form input fields

    <input  type="submit" value="Submit" />
}
```

Comment: Here, How can i add data.

Comment: data means? input field?

Comment: Yes, Input field data to controller method

Comment: `Input field data to controller method` - What does it mean? Check my updated answer!

Comment: suppose i ll add like this   <input type="text" name="Name" />,  How Can i pass this data to Controller Method

Comment: Look at the code properly I have posted. Everything is here. When you will click the `submit` button it will called the controller method specified  in `Ajax.BeginForm("MethodName", "ControllerName", new AjaxOptions`

Comment: It's working fine, but i am struggling to send parameter.

Comment: Then mark it answer by clicking the check on the left side of the answer please.

Comment: i'll marked this is correct answer, and this also working fine, can you just explain to add parameter from here to destination??

Comment: Okay! Let me check. I shall back to comment.

Answer (score 0):

It's depending on what is the issue you are having while try to using the specific code that you have been provided
Can you kindly tell us the specific problem
The solution maybe easier than finding alternative ways

Comment: Actually above mentioned are working fine. I just asking this question to know a new method.